# Paper concerning distributing quantum computation on many small quantum computers

Tags: resource-request, tensor-networks

I remember reading a paper that described how a quantum circuit on a large amount of qubits can be simulated by doing many runs on a smaller quantum computer. They used techniques from tensor networks. I believe it was published in PRL somewhere after 2018, but I haven't been able to find it again.
It is not this paper: [Computational Speedups Using Small Quantum Devices (Dunjko *et al.*, 2018)](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.121.250501).

Does anybody know which paper I'm talking about it, or have I simply dreamt up the existence of this paper?

Comment: Is there a restriction on the type of state being simulated? For shapes simulable by a MERA-style circuit (https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0610099.pdf) this sounds feasible.

Comment: The paper concerned universal quantum circuits, and they used some kind of graph theoretic property (where 2-qubit gates form the edges), in order to find right places to 'cut' the circuit. The simulation was not efficient, which is what you would expect if BQP$\neq$ BPP

Comment: Was is a Divide-and-Conquer approach though? In my group, similar ideas have been mentioned recently

Comment: @Marsl: I'm not sure what you mean by Divide-and-Conquer.

Comment: Is it this one? https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.00102.pdf

Comment: @Marsl: yes! That is indeed the one. Thank you!